# Does IronPython support Testoob for unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, ironpython

Does IronPython support Testoob for unit testing?

If so, how?

Comment: In general - write your unit tests as for CPython, and you can run the `testoob` command line script with IronPython, or use `testoob.main()` inside your test file as usual. The Python standard library should be in the `IRONPYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes](http://groups.google.com/group/testoob/browse_thread/thread/ff2a026433539fb0/441ceb2b41208ec5?lnk=gst&q=ironpython#441ceb2b41208ec5). The author has said he's interested in developing it further, but (at v1.15) it has "preliminary" IronPython support.

I suggest you follow it up in the [testoob Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/testoob) where the author of testoob is active.

Comment: +1 - Testoob developer here, and the Google group is a good place to contact us